# GDB can't load kernel symbol correctly with KASLR enabled

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

With KASLR enabled there will be an offset between symbol file and actual symbol location.

```
% cat /proc/kallsyms| grep '\<jiffies_64\>'
ffffffff86805000 D jiffies_64
% objdump -t /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.13.0-1-amd64 | grep '\<jiffies_64\>'
ffffffff81c05000 g     O .data  0000000000000008 jiffies_64
```

Find the .text section location, so I can load the symbol file correctly:

```
% cat /proc/kallsyms | grep '\<_text\>'
ffffffff85c00000 T _text
```

But even if I loaded the symbol file at correction location:

```
% sudo gdb -c /proc/kcore
GNU gdb (Debian 8.0-1) 8.0
(gdb) add-symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.13.0-1-amd64 0xffffffff85c00000
add symbol table from file "/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.13.0-1-amd64" at
    .text_addr = 0xffffffff85c00000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.13.0-1-amd64...done.
```

GDB still giving the wrong symbol location:

```
(gdb) p &jiffies_64
$1 = (u64 *) 0xffffffff81c05000 <jiffies_64>
```

How do I force GDB to load the symbol at correct location ?

Comment: the internet says that the best way is to temporarily disable `kaslr` just as @ttsiodras said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice the second field in the line of `jiffies_64` symbol.

```
# grep -w jiffies_64 /proc/kallsyms 
ffffffffbb005000 D jiffies_64
```

The second field is the symbol type (see `nm(1)`). In this case, `D` means that the `jiffies_64` symbol is located at the **data** segment.

You have loaded your vmlinux file and only specified the address of the **text** segment, but since `jiffies_64` is not in the text segment but in the data segment, it didn't help you.

So first you need to find the start address of your kernel's **data** segment, which is the address of the `_sdata` symbol in `/proc/kallsyms`.

```
# grep -w _sdata /proc/kallsyms
ffffffffbb000000 D _sdata
```

Then you need to load your vmlinux file with the start address of the kernel's data segment.

```
# gdb -q -c /proc/kcore
(gdb) add-symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.12.14-122.37-default.debug -s .data 0xffffffffbb000000
add symbol table from file "/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.12.14-122.37-default.debug" at
        .data_addr = 0xffffffffbb000000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.12.14-122.37-default.debug...
(gdb) p &jiffies_64
$1 = (u64 *) 0xffffffffbb005000 <jiffies_64>
```

And - voila, now the address of `jiffies_64` is `0xffffffffbb0050000`, which is exactly what you see in `/proc/kallsyms`.

Comment: Haven't verified it, because it is a 6 years old question. But it looks reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion, debugging kernels is hard enough without having the symbols "dance around" every time you reboot.

That is to say, it's maybe worth considering passing `nokaslr` to your kernel - at least while you're debugging...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17802984)

Comment: @Bart: I humbly disagree; this question was IMHO a case of the XY problem - so I provided an answer that solves the root issue, that caused the question...

Comment: @ttsiodras there was no XY problem here. KASLR is a legitimate feature that is used; I use it myself; and telling someone to disable KASLR to debug is not an answer.

(sorry for necrobump: I came here looking for answers and found none)